# What happens when you update PHP while your server is running?

Tags: linux, php, update

I'm serving files with Apache and PHP-FPM via FCGI.

When I run `yum update` on a live server, what happens when PHP gets updated?

I can imagine three scenarios:

- `php-fpm` is stopped, then restarted after the package has been updated
- `php-fpm` keeps using the previous PHP version until it's restarted
- `php-fpm` keeps running and switches PHP versions on the fly, potentially even in the middle of executing a script (e.g. running a script with the old version, and an include with the new version)

Which of these reflects what actually happens?

Comment: You've given little information about your distribution. One can only guess that it's RPM-based (due to *yum*).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the .spec file, php-fpm will be restarted, meaning any running processes will be stopped. See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/blob/master/php/php56/php56.spec

Answer (score 0):

To be more predictable, I'd strongly suggest against running yum update on live server, instead you should create non-php maintenance page and serve that while you're updating php and then switch back to your php application once you're done and restart php-fpm as well.